# jquery slideUp and slidedown callback repeating

Tags: jquery, html

Im creating an jquery accordion and the triggering effect is onclick, im having problem because there was an excess action of slideUp and slideDown in the last level of ul, the error was occurred when i do this following actions

-

1. click "Button"
2. -choose and click A or any(A,B or C)
3. -then select and click A.1 or any..
4. -then click again their parent A
5. -then click A to open again
6. -click any of the childs

As you notice, you click only once but the slideUp and slideDown was trigger.
here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ins-type").appendTo("li.prd");
$("li.prd>a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#ins-type").slideToggle();
});
$("#ins-type>li>a").stop().click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("act")){
       $(this).parent().find('ul').find(".act").find('.the-ins-desc').slideUp().parent().removeClass("act");
        $(this).parent().find("ul.the-ins").slideUp();
        $(this).parent().removeClass("act");
    }else{
        $("#ins-type>li").removeClass("act").find("ul.the-ins").slideUp();
        $(this).parent().addClass("act");
        $(this).parent().find("ul.the-ins").slideDown(function(){
                $(this).find('li').children('a').click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if($(this).parent().hasClass("act")){
                        $(this).parent().removeClass("act");
                        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp();
                        console.log("clise");
                    }else{
                        $(".the-ins>li").removeClass("act").find('.the-ins-desc').slideUp();
                        $(this).parent().addClass("act").find("ul").stop().slideDown();
                        console.log("open");
                    }
                    return false;
                });
        });
    }
});
});
```

[Fiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/mx64mswn/)

Answer (score 0):

Your last "if, else" statement, put return false in the brackets.

https://jsfiddle.net/mx64mswn/1/

```
if($(this).parent().hasClass("act")){
                        $(this).parent().removeClass("act");
                        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp();
                        console.log("clise");
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        $(".the-ins>li").removeClass("act").find('.the-ins-desc').slideUp();
                        $(this).parent().addClass("act").find("ul").stop().slideDown();
                        console.log("open");
                        return false;
                    }
```